# Application cannot locate resource file in Visual Studio 2010 designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I made a custom user control that contains a `PictureBox`, which renders a PNG image from a resource folder:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Overlay with the shape of well
    Image transparentImg = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\Resources\\reservoir_img.png");
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(transparentImg, new Point(0, 0));  
}
```

When I build and run the application the user control paint method renders PNG just fine (path must be right), but when I preview the form designer in Visual Studio 2010 then it doesn't render. It only shows exception:

[image: FileNotFoundException]

I can develop and test my application, but it's kind of annoying to design forms when you only see exception texts.

Comment: Do you need to change this image dinamically at run-time? If no, why don't you add it to your resources.resx file and use the Properties.Settings.Default.NameOfYourImageResource ?

Comment: Path is not correct. It only works if you run your application from your debug/release folder, but Visual Studio is not running from that folder.

Comment: BTW. Loading the image in the paint event is probably not a good idea (unless your image is constantly changing)

Comment: Thanks. Got it fixed by using resources.resx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use resources.resx file:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.reservoir_img, new Point(0, 0));
```